# MySQL join 4 tables without repetition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables and I want to select the information from these tables using one query.

I have a table name

`tbl_marketing`

```
db_maid db_client db_status db_process
4        test      done     ddd
```

`tbl_meeting`

```
db_meetingid db_meetingsubject db_mid
1               test            4
```

`tbl_phonecall`

```
db_phid db_subject db_mid
1       ggg          4
2       fff          4
```

`tbl_email`

```
db_eid  db_email db_mid

1        xxx       4
```

**Remark:** this is an example of my 4 tables. My tables contain more columns 
`db_mid` is the id of `tbl_marketing`

I want to select all information without repetition

**I use this query:**

```
select
      marketing.*,
 meeting.db_meetingid,meeting.db_meetingsubject,meeting.db_sd,meeting.db_dd,meeting.db_duration as meetingDuration,meeting.db_place,meeting.db_mom,meeting.db_momattache,meeting.db_status as meetingStatus,meeting.db_nextmeeting,meeting.db_lastmeeting,meeting.db_attendees,meeting.db_note as meetingNote,meeting.db_mid,
      phonecall.db_phid,phonecall.db_subject as phoneSubject,phonecall.db_desc as phoneDesc,phonecall.db_nextdate,phonecall.db_doc,phonecall.db_duration as phoneDuration,phonecall.db_phstatus,phonecall.db_pnote,phonecall.db_client as phoneClient,phonecall.db_crf,phonecall.db_callto,phonecall.db_phone as phonecallPhone,phonecall.db_logs as phoneLogs,phonecall.db_mid,phonecall.db_dateedit as phoneEdit,phonecall.db_phdate,
   email.db_eid,email.db_edate,email.db_esubject,email.db_edesc,email.db_erf,email.db_emailto,email.db_email as eEmail,email.db_dos,email.db_dor,email.db_estatus,email.db_logs as eLogs,email.db_note as eNote,
   location.db_location as location,
   location.db_lid,
   company.db_company as com,
   company.db_coid,
   subcompany.db_subid,
   subcompany.db_subcompany as sub,
   user.db_uid,
   concat(user.db_fname,' ' ,user.db_lname) as tr,
   subj.db_subjid,
   subj.db_subject as s
      from tbl_marketing as marketing
      left join tbl_location as location
      on
      marketing.db_location=location.db_lid
      left join tbl_meeting as meeting
      on
      marketing.db_maid=meeting.db_mid
      left join tbl_phonecall as phonecall
      on
      marketing.db_maid=phonecall.db_mid
      left join tbl_email as email
      on
      marketing.db_maid=email.db_mid
      left join tbl_company as company
      on
      marketing.db_companyname=company.db_coid
      left join tbl_subcompany as subcompany
      on
      marketing.db_subcompany=subcompany.db_subid
      left join tbl_user as user
      on
      marketing.db_transfered=user.db_uid
      left join tbl_subject as subj
      on
      phonecall.db_subject=subj.db_subjid
      where
      marketing.db_maid='$read'
      and
      meeting.db_mid='$read'
      and
      email.db_mid='$read'
      and
      phonecall.db_mid='$read'
```

I use this query to select the information  but when I have 2 rows, the same `db_mid` as `tbl_phonecall` in the example, then the information is duplicated as follows:

**table marketing**

1               test            4

1               test            4

**table phonecall**

1       ggg          4

2       fff          4

**table meeting**

1               test            4

1               test            4

**table email**

1        xxx       4

1        xxx       4

As visible above all tables have a duplicate value without phonecall because he have 2 rows I want to show all the information without this repetition

if I use group by mid I don't receive the second information in `tbl_phonecall`

```
$rows=array();
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$row[]=$rows;}
<table>
foreach($rows as row){
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['phID'];?></td>
</tr>
} 
</table>
```

output

```
# subject mid

1  test   4

2  ggg    4
```

not like this

1,2 test,ggg 4,4

Comment: In most situations, you get the data as you are (with the duplicate info), and do a break sort in the calling application to display the dup data once. An alternative is to do the group by, and use group_concat on the columns that may have multiple rows. This will produce a comma separated list in those columns.

Comment: @SloanThrasher can you please give me an example

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you only have duplicates in the phonecall table, the following should work. If other left joined tables can have duplicates, just add GROUP_CONCAT as needed.

```
select
    marketing.*,
    meeting.db_meetingid,
    meeting.db_meetingsubject,
    meeting.db_sd,
    meeting.db_dd,
    meeting.db_duration as meetingDuration,
    meeting.db_place,
    meeting.db_mom,
    meeting.db_momattache,
    meeting.db_status as meetingStatus,
    meeting.db_nextmeeting,
    meeting.db_lastmeeting,
    meeting.db_attendees,
    meeting.db_note as meetingNote,
    meeting.db_mid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_phid) as phID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_subject) as phoneSubject,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_desc) as phoneDesc,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_nextdate) as phNextDate,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_doc) as phDoc,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_duration) as phoneDuration,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_phstatus) as phStatus,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_pnote) as phPNote,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_client) as phoneClient,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_crf) as phCrf,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_callto) as phCallTo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_phone) as phonecallPhone,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_logs) as phoneLogs,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_mid) as phMid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_dateedit) as phoneEdit,
    GROUP_CONCAT(phonecall.db_phdate) as phdate,
    email.db_eid,
    email.db_edate,
    email.db_esubject,
    email.db_edesc,
    email.db_erf,
    email.db_emailto,
    email.db_email as eEmail,
    email.db_dos,
    email.db_dor,
    email.db_estatus,
    email.db_logs as eLogs,
    email.db_note as eNote,
    location.db_location as location,
    location.db_lid,
    company.db_company as com,
    company.db_coid,
    subcompany.db_subid,
    subcompany.db_subcompany as sub,
    user.db_uid,
    concat(user.db_fname,' ' ,user.db_lname) as tr,
    subj.db_subjid,
    subj.db_subject as s
from tbl_marketing as marketing
left join tbl_location as location
    on marketing.db_location=location.db_lid
left join tbl_meeting as meeting
    on marketing.db_maid=meeting.db_mid
left join tbl_phonecall as phonecall
    on marketing.db_maid=phonecall.db_mid
left join tbl_email as email
    on marketing.db_maid=email.db_mid
left join tbl_company as company
    on marketing.db_companyname=company.db_coid
left join tbl_subcompany as subcompany
    on marketing.db_subcompany=subcompany.db_subid
left join tbl_user as user
    on marketing.db_transfered=user.db_uid
left join tbl_subject as subj
    on phonecall.db_subject=subj.db_subjid
where marketing.db_maid='$read' and
    meeting.db_mid='$read' and
    email.db_mid='$read' and
    phonecall.db_mid='$read'
GROUP BY meeting.db_mid
```

Comment: is there another method to do that because i want to print each row alone

Comment: What does that mean? How are you printing? PHP script?

Comment: i use php to print the result in an html table

Comment: What do you mean by _"i want to print each row alone"_ -- IOW, edit your question and show your sample output, and add the PHP code you have tried.

Comment: please check above

Comment: The PHP code won't execute and you didn't show an example of the output you want.

Comment: please check above the output

Comment: In that case, drop the group by and group_concat from the SQL, and edit your php to only output the repeating columns once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143958/discussion-between-mohamad-mohamad-and-sloan-thrasher).